# String comparison with special character "**" === "**" given false in TS

Tags: typescript

String comparison with special character for example  text === "**" given false in TS when text is "**".

I have tried...
const val: string = obj.text.trim()
where text == "**" coming I can see via debug.

```
  if (val === "**") {
        // False 
  }
```

also tried with == / trim() / toString() options.

Solution:
The issue was that I Used '∗' star instead of '*'. Notice the diffrence. Language and keyboard issues. While working with people across the world we need to take care of such things as well.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].  As it stands it doesn't look like you've given enough information for someone to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Check your assumptions; AFAICT string comparison in TS works just fine.

Comment: I have got the problem ... Used '∗' star instead of '*'. Language and keyboard issue. Silly mistakes and it's a time-waster.

Comment: @NCG: please don't edit the answer into the question, instead post it as an answer instead, that way it'll become useful for others that might run into the same problem.